# Extending generic objective c class in swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I am slowly adding more swift files to codebase. 
Suppose I have class in Objective c:

```
ListData<Type : CSJSONData *> : ServerData <CSListData>
```

I want to subclass it in swift class like this:

```
@objc class ArticlesData: ListData<Article>
```

Compiler gives me error:

```
Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' because they are not directly visible from Objective-C
Replace '@objc ' with ''
```

But I need to have it @objc to keep available in my objc part of code ! How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The Swift Programming Language (4.2), Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html):

> The compiler implicitly adds the objc attribute to subclasses of any class defined in Objective-C. However, the subclass must not be generic, and must not inherit from any generic classes. You can explicitly add the objc attribute to a subclass that meets these criteria, to specify its Objective-C name as discussed below.

Unfortunately for you this is pretty definitive.

Comment: My development with swift in shared codebase can be named fighting with swift compiler and looking on build progress line ...